# Passing nested array as parameter for function in VBA results in compile error "Expected: ="

Tags: excel, function, vba, parameters, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to Construct an array (testSheets) that holds a file name and a file path as strings. I then wish to contain this array inside of another array (shtsTmpl). Then, I want to pass the strings within the nested array into a function's parameters (copySheets) to simply return the combined file path in a msgbox.

This first bit of code successfully returns "TSTSheets.xlsx" in a msg box.

```
Sub prepSheets()
 Dim testSheets() As Variant
 ReDim testSheets(0)
 testSheets(0) = "TSTSheets.xlsx"

 Dim shtsTmpl() As Variant
 shtsTmpl = Array(testSheets)

 copySheets (shtsTmpl(0)(0))

End Sub

Function copySheets(srcName As String)
 MsgBox (srcName)
End Function
```

This second bit of code returns a compile error that says "Expected: =" at the line that calls the copySheets function and I do not understand why.

```
Sub testSheets()
 Dim testSheets() As Variant
 ReDim testSheets(1)
 testSheets(0) = "TSTSheets.xlsx"
 testSheets(1) = "C:\"

 Dim shtsTmpl() As Variant
 shtsTmpl = Array(testSheets)

 copySheets (shtsTmpl(0)(0),shtsTmpl(0)(1))
End Sub

Function copySheets(srcName As String, srcPath As String)
 MsgBox (srcPath & srcName)
End Function
```

Can someone please explain to me why the code compiles correctly when the function has one parameter and incorrectly when the function has two parameters?

Please let me know if you need further explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding a `Call` keyword just before the `copySheets` call, or remove the outer parentheses around the parameter list.

Comment: Both changes (no parentheses and Call keyword) result in a new compile error: "ByRef argument type mismatch". I will have to investigate this.

Comment: Is `copySheets` a Function or a Sub ?  If a Function, does it return a value?

Comment: copySheets is a Function. It does not return a value. I found the soultion, given Robert Harvey's suggestion. I simply needed to remove the Parentheses and add a ByVal before both of the parameters defined in the function. Though, I can't say I'm sure as to why this works.

Comment: Strings are probably treated as values in vba, while arrays (or any part of them) are probably treated as references.  Nobody ever accused vba of being logically consistent, and this seems to be a quirk of the language, given that a single parameter works OK.